# Prove that $(n)_k$ is $O(n^k)$.

Tags: limits

I am working on trying to show that $(n)_k$ is $O(n^k)$. I know that generally you will want to take an infinite limit to find the Big O but I'm not totally sure how to do so with a falling factorial. I know that:

$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{(n)_k}{n^k} = 0$$

I know that the limit is zero as the falling factorial will only take k terms of the factorial which will be much less than an exponent of k. However, I'm not really sure if there is another way to show this algebraically or not.

Comment: I think you might want to test this out on fixed $k$; e.g. for $k=1$ you have $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{n}$$ and for $k=2$ you have $$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n\cdot (n-1)}{n^2}.$$
You can reduce this in various ways, but you should learn that the limit is actually $1$, not $0$ - which will make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Oops. I'm not sure why I thought the limit went to zero. Everything now makes perfect sense to me.